# Indexing a tensor with None in PyTorch

Tags: indexing, syntax, pytorch, tensor

I've seen this syntax to index a tensor in PyTorch, not sure what it means:

```
v = torch.div(t, n[:, None])
```

where `v`, `t`, and `n` are tensors.

What is the role of "`None`" here? I can't seem to find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Similar to NumPy you can insert a singleton dimension (*"unsqueeze"* a dimension) by indexing this dimension with `None`. In turn `n[:, None]` will have the effect of inserting a new dimension on `dim=1`. This is equivalent to `n.unsqueeze(dim=1)`:

```
>>> n = torch.rand(3, 100, 100)

>>> n[:, None].shape
(3, 1, 100, 100)

>>> n.unsqueeze(1).shape
(3, 1, 100, 100)
```

---

Here are some other types of *`None` indexings*.

In the example above `:` is was used as a placeholder to designate the first dimension `dim=0`. If you want to insert a dimension on `dim=2`, you can add a second `:` as `n[:, :, None]`.

You can also *place* `None` with respect to the last dimension instead. To do so you can use the [ellipsis](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/brackets/ellipsis.html) syntax `...`:

- `n[..., None]` will insert a dimension last, *i.e.* `n.unsqueeze(dim=-1)`.
- `n[..., None, :]` on the before last dimension, *i.e.* `n.unsqueeze(dim=-2)`.