# TensorDataSet "size mismatch between tensors"

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have 4 matrices of size 64x64 that were stacked (Torch.Stack) to create a size of [4,64,64] and are meant to be the inputs for my TensorDataSet. I have 1 matrix of 64x64 that is meant to be output for my TensorDataSet. When I load these into the TensorDataSet(inputs,outputs), I get the size mismatch.

If I take 1 input and 1 output each with size 64x64 the TensorDataSet will accept this. However, I want to pass in 4 input values that correspond to 1 output value. For example the first value in the [0,0] position of each input has a relationship to the [0,0] position of the output.

I tried using squeeze methods and didn't have any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look carefully at the stack trace of the error raised by [`TensorDataset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.TensorDataset), you will see:

> `assert all(tensors[0].size(0) == tensor.size(0) for tensor in tensors)`

This means all tensors must have the same size along the first dimension (the dataset size).

In your case, **one** `4x64x64` tensor corresponds to **one** 64x64 tensor, in other words, the inputs to TensorDataset must be shaped `(1,4,64,64)` and `(1,64,64)` for the input and output, respectively. Therefore you need to add an extra dimension on both (with [`None` indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69797614/indexing-a-tensor-with-none-in-pytorch) or [`unsqueeze`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.unsqueeze.html)):

```
x = torch.rand(4,64,64)
y = torch.rand(64,64)

dataset = TensorDataset(x[None], y[None])
```